# how to detect tap home-button twice in ios9

Tags: swift, ios9, uiapplicationdelegate, home-button

In my app which am writing to learn **swift** and iOS9, I'm trying to pause my `NStimer` when user double click the home button and becomes at app switcher, accoridng to programming ios9 matt neuberg, when The user double-clicks the Home button, The user can now work in the app switcher interface. If your app is frontmost, your app delegate receives this message:
`applicationWillResignActive`:

But my timer only pauses when I tap home button once and when I tap twice and have the app switcher, I see my timer counting, any ideas?

Comment: show you code in `applicationWillResignActive `

Comment: Shud i include code in applicationWillResi‌​gnActive  am just using nsnotification along woth my selector action as written below                       override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // pause game when home button tapped twice.
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
        selector: #selector(ViewController.pauseGame),
        name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
  }  inside pause game func, am caller timer.invalidate()

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this lines in your AppDelegate.swift:

```
static let kAppDidBecomeActive = "kAppDidBecomeActive"
static let kAppWillResignActive = "kAppWillResignActive"

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Your application is now the active one
    // Take into account that this method will be called when your application is launched and your timer may not initialized yet
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("kAppDidBecomeActive", object: nil)
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Home button is pressed twice
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("kAppWillResignActive", object: nil)
}
```

In addition, set your view controller as the observer to those notifications:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(pauseGame), name: AppDelegate.kAppWillResignActive, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(resumeGame), name: AppDelegate.AppDelegate.kAppDidBecomeActive, object: nil)

}
```